# Angular - Return value as undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angularfire2, angularfire5

I have the following function:

```
  redirect() {
    this.afs.collection('links').doc(this.path).ref.get().then(function(doc) {
      if(doc.exists) {
        // define data and clicks
        var data = doc.data();
        var clicks = doc.data().clicks;
        // Update clicks
        doc.ref.update({
          'clicks': (clicks + 1)
        })
        .then(function() {
          if(data.landing == false) {
            // Redirect to url
            return false;
          } else {
            // Stay for Landing Page
            return true;
          }
        });
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/404']);
      }
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
  }
```

When I try the following in onNgInit:

```
console.log(this.redirect());
```

It returns undefined.
I'm not sure what to do to either be able to set a value to true or false to return true or false.

Comment: make a callback

Comment: @RandyStivenValentín Could you explain what you mean? To be honest, im still learning, and am not familiar with everything.

Answer (score 0):

The function `redirect` doesn't return anything, right now. But it looks like you're working with a Promise.  Try refactoring to return that promise:

```
redirect() {

   return this.afs.collection('links').doc(this.path).ref.get().then(function(doc) {
      if(doc.exists) {
        // define data and clicks
        var data = doc.data();
        var clicks = doc.data().clicks;
        // Update clicks
        doc.ref.update({
          'clicks': (clicks + 1)
        })
        .then(function() {
          if(data.landing == false) {
            // Redirect to url
            return false;
          } else {
            // Stay for Landing Page
            return true;
          }
        });
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/404']);
      }
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
  }
```

So now you can print out the value when the promise resolves.

```
this.redirect().then(value => console.log(value))
```

Comment: I'm trying to specifically return true or false, if data.landing is false or true. Or set a value like `landing: boolean;` to true or false.

I also tried what you proposed and it still returned undefined